# Pass URL params in route - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have a URL

```
https://website.com/enable/code=react/string=true
```

My React router looks like this

```
<Router history={history}>
        <Route 
            path="/" 
            component={App}

        >
            <IndexRoute component={Page1} />                                
            <Route path="/enable/language='dynamicVal'/string='dynamicVal'>{page2()}</Route>    
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

Now the `Route path` i need to get the dynamic value for `language` and `string`

I have tried this.

```
/enable/language=(/:react)/string=(/:true)
```

How and where to define the dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the path param approach and structure your Routes like

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route 
        path="/" 
        component={App}
    >
        <IndexRoute component={Page1} />                                
        <Route path="/enable/:language/:codeString'>{page2()}</Route>    
    </Route>
</Router>
```

and in your component you get get the path params like

`this.props.params.language` and `this.props.params.codeString` if you are using `react-router-v3` or below

and

`this.props.match.params.language` and `this.props.match.params.codeString` if you are using `react-router-v4`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming react-router v4 (not tested on v3, which is what you seem to be using?), you can define a Route as such:

```
<Route
  exact path="/enable/language=:language/string=:stringVal"
  component={YourComponent} />`
```

In `YourComponent`, both params will be available under `this.props.match.params.language` and `this.props.match.params.stringVal`, respectively.

See [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/383jlvqp55) for a working example.